# Putting my variables under a namespace

Tags: javascript, variables, object, namespaces, encapsulation

How can I create an object containing my variables using the same variable names, or with other words, how can I put my variables under a namespace?

```
var a = "variable";
var b = "variable";

var obj = {
    a : a
    b : b
}
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this than this?

EDIT:

Let me clarify - I already have the variables a and b declared somewhere. Eventually at one point I want to send them all over to another function for example, but I want all variables under one namespace - obj. So Instead of doing the tedious redeclaring every single variable using the same variable names and same variable values (the variable itself) I thought maybe there was a shorthand way: like

```
var obj = objectify(a, b);
```

I wondered if there was something similar already build into the javascript library.

Comment: Only by declaring them directly as properties of the object.

Comment: Surely by doing what your doing your negating the point of name spacing in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

As you are actually not putting the variables in the object but only copying their content into properties with the same names, you don't need to create the variables at all:

```
var obj = {
  a: "variable",
  b: "variable"
};
```

Note the comma between the properties, which is needed, and the semicolon after the object declaration, which is recommended.

You can also create an empty object, and add properties to it afterwards (or any combination you like):

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = "variable";
obj.b = "variable";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "variable";
var b = "variable";
var obj = {};
obj[a] = a;
obj[b] = b;
```

Sorry for layout, but WYSIWYG editor has not any tabs(

Comment: @Felix Kling, thank you for editing. But why editor doesn't have any buttons and preview?

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
  a: "variable",
  b: "variable"
};
```

I may be misunderstanding your request here

Answer (score 0):

There are no namespaces in the current version of javascript, so the only way is to put these variables in an object, which is what you did. You can also create an object and assign variables to it, though it is not shorter:

```
var x = {};
x.foo = "foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't usefully put *existing* variables into a namespace object.

In particular, if you have:

```
var a = 1;
var b = "test";
var c = { ... };  // some object

var NS = {
    a: a,
    b: b,
    c: c
};
```

Then changes to `a` or `b` will not affect `NS.a` or `NS.b`, and vice-versa, since the entries in the `NS` object are *copies* of the originals.

However changes to the *content* of `c` will affect `NS.c` (and vice versa), since `c` is a *reference* to an object.

However anything you do that subsequently changes the reference stored in `NS.c` will break that link.